# nginx rewrite all to https except for a subpath?

Tags: nginx

I want all urls that are http to be redirected to https.

http://example.com/blah/blah

changes to

https://example.com/blah/blah

I have this snippet in my nginx conf that achieves this effect:

```
upstream examplewsgicluster {
    server unix://tmp/example.sock;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    beta.example.com www.example.com example.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass examplewsgicluster;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 700;
    }
}
```

how can I edit this rule so that paths that begin with /admin/ do not get redirected?

so http://example.com/admin/blah/blah does not get redirected.

Answer (score 3):

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name beta.example.com www.example.com example.com;

    location /admin {
        [ ... ] 
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question to show a more detailed nginx config

Comment: @nbv4 Happy to hear it. Although this changes nothing to this answer.